# Landscape & Portrait Graphics for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiimageview, orientation

I have a single view with two custom layouts, one for Landscape and one for Portrait. These view objects also (currently) have two images, one for each view.

Example: one image has a text component. To avoid stretching the image, we've made one for portrait and one for landscape.

What I'm trying to avoid is is a bunch of if statements that determine which orientation is being shown and thus which image to use. Is there a way to avoid all this extra code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of...using image names set accordingly. I mean you can name them image_portrait.png and image_landscape.png and then in your `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation..` method do something like this:

```
NSString *orientation = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) ? @"portrait" : @"landscape";
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%@",orientation]]];
```

I don't know of anything you can do more than this. Sure , this doesn't look like much of an improvement but if you have more images it will be quite useful.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!